# Changing attributes and colors in leanback android

Tags: android, leanback

Leanback internally is using some default colors and attr.I want to override it .Is it possible if yes how can do it ?

Basically these attribures I want to override  attr name="playbackProgressPrimaryColor" format="reference|color" 
        attr name="playbackControlsIconHighlightColor" format="reference|color"

Comment: Please, specify your question what do you mean by default colors?

Comment: <color name="lb_playback_progress_color_no_theme">#ff40c4ff</color>
    <color name="lb_playback_icon_highlight_no_theme">#ff40c4ff</color>
    <color name="lb_playback_secondary_progress_color">#33FFFFFF</color>
    <color name="lb_playback_background_progress_color">#19FFFFFF</color>

Comment: I think, it will be more readable, if you add this to your question. Thank you

Comment: either you can override the default resources coping to your values. or you can also change by creating a new style for them. I suggest you create styles as overriding might get you in problems in future.

Answer (score 0):

either you can override the default resources coping to your values. or you can also change by creating a new style for them. I suggest you create styles as overriding might get you in problems in future